# Selenium, WebDriver : Get Element, " <a href=Javascript " with changing variables

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

javascript button source to get element:

```html
<a href="JavaScript:onclick=bookProsecc('20220512','1550','A','B','0','','')">
    <img src="/image/cal_app.jpg" alt="C">
</a>
```

I used find_element using href with just before changing variables but I think it doesn't work.

```
submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[@href='JavaScript:onclick=bookProsecc(']")
```

What is the best way to access the button element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//img[@src='/image/cal_app.jpg']/..")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
submit_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//a[starts-with(@href,'JavaScript:onclick=bookProsecc(')]")
```

Try this one where the href starts with a certain string.